# How to read files using the OPENDATASOURCE method?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to understand what a particular piece of source code does. The original author has written the following excerpt:

```
/*******************************************/
-- Inserează în tabela temporară.
/*******************************************/
INSERT INTO #tmp
(
    [tip]
  , [ev]
  , [ap]
  , [cant]
  , [preț]
  , [data]
)
SELECT *
FROM
OPENDATASOURCE
(
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
  , 'Data Source=C:\ETU; Extended Properties="TEXT; HDR=yes; FMT=DELIMITED"'
)...[EV#csv]
```

When I am executing this piece of code in SSMS, I get the following error:

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "EV#csv". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

[MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276845(v=sql.80).aspx) shows certain syntaxes for linked servers, but I do not think that the original author meant that.

There is a certain file on the hard disk which full path is `C:\ETU\EV20150126000001.csv`.

I have attempted to rename the file to the `EV#csv` new name, yet to no avail.

`SELECT @@VERSION` says:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (Intel X86)   Sep 16 2010 20:09:22   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 5.1  (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

Comment: The Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is data access library for Excel/Access so the code is trying to read data from CSV file into a temporary table. The DATA Source parameter should point to the filename though. If you change the source to  '('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
  , 'Data Source=C:\ETU\EV20150126000001.csv; Extended Properties="TEXT; HDR=yes; FMT=DELIMITED"'
)' you will read the data from the file

Comment: @Spörri: Strange. It still complains about some linked server. The file path is correct - with double quotes or not - yet the following message appears:

"OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "'C:\ETU\EV20150126000001.csv' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"."

Comment: ok, haven't done this for a long time: http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/code-library/ad-hoc-querying/ad-hoc-querying-text-files/ 

  SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                             'Data Source=C:\Temp\;Extended Properties="Text;HDR=YES;"')...[test#csv] Will open test.csv from c:\temp so change [EV#csv] to [EV20150126000001#csv] but since this is a CSV file I would use openrowset bulk: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2011/01/so-you-want-to-read-csv-files-huh.html

Comment: Yep. That did the trick. So, maybe that '#' sign is a place-holder for a period. The final source code went into the following version: "SELECT *
    FROM
    OPENDATASOURCE
    (
        'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
      , 'Data Source=C:\ETU; Extended Properties="TEXT; HDR=yes; FMT=DELIMITED"'
    )...[EV20150126000001#csv]". Thank you for commenting. Maybe you can create an answer with that, if you feel like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is data access library for Excel/Access so the code is trying to read data from CSV file into a temporary table.

If you change the source to `OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Data Source=C:\ETU;Extended Properties="Text;HDR=YES;"')...[etu#csv]` you will open c:\etu\etu.csv so changing the last parameter to `...EV20150126000001#csv` will open your file. See:http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/code-library/ad-hoc-querying/ As this is a CSV file I would prefer to use openrowset bulk as the Jet.OLEDB drivers are "interesting" on 64bit platforms:  see: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2011/01/ for further ideas.